# Bittorrent maintain states among multiple peers

Tags: p2p, bittorrent

I am following the [Kristen Widman](http://www.kristenwidman.com/blog/33/how-to-write-a-bittorrent-client-part-1/) tutorial for writing a bittorrent client, as well as following the [Wiki](https://wiki.theory.org/index.php/BitTorrentSpecification#Tracker_Response), however I have a point of confusion that I haven't been able to clear up from online resources.

So far I have been able to send a tracker request and receive a list of peers, whose IP addresses and ports I've stored like this:

```
[{'IP': IPv4Address('76.126.244.88'), 'port': 6881}, ... ]
```

Kristen suggests in her tutorial that I try to connect to a single peer first. I suppose I'd try to connect with the first peer in the list first, so far so good.

With regards to each peer, however, there are certain states like 'am_choking' , 'peer_choking', 'am_interested', 'peer_interested'. For each peer in my list, do I need to keep track of each of these states?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, connections to each peer need to maintain an independent set of states to remember what the latest status sent by the remote is.

This is explicitly mentioned in the [official bittorrent specification](http://bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0003.html#peer-protocol):

> Connections contain two bits of state on either end: choked or not, and interested or not.

and [on the wiki](https://wiki.theory.org/index.php/BitTorrentSpecification#Peer_wire_protocol_.28TCP.29) too:

> A client must maintain state information for each connection that it has with a remote peer: